# Convert Magento 1.5 to 1.9 and replace with new theme, points to take care

Tags: php, database, magento, upgrade

I have Magento website with about 1000 electrical products.
The current version is 1.5.

I now have purchased new template but not sure if that will fill up with my all requirements or not.  Or require any customization.

But with new design I also want to update Magento to 1.9.

Want only general answers to below or your thoughts: 
1) Steps for up-gradation
2) Checklist of points I should take care in doing this considering above scenario?
3) Will upgrading to new design and new Magento version, affect my current database or functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest to you install new 1.9 magento and add your purchased theme in to mangento then task backup of your data base and create a new backup only on catalog, sales and customer all table then add this table into you magento 1.9 database first delete these table in 1.9 database also.

And yes copy & paste your media folder in new magento set up, if your have on your cache in 1.5 also copy & paste your var>cache folder.

during this process not execute your site.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, will keep in mind the points you noted...

Comment: hi you have complete your work?

Comment: Hello, yes, the developer did it, we are planning to take old database back up of product, customer tables and all and revamp website in 1.9.  As the time for new site and old site conversion was same...  But thanks for your answer.

Comment: if you want your all order and customer also take customer & sales tables, and if you have extra modules in your old site just install new and replace module table in your old database. you will get your old data....

Answer (score 1):

For Magento upgrades we normally follow the Magento WIKI

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database

The procedure is more time consuming but it will ensure you have a stable upgraded site when you are finished.

I would NEVER use Magento connect to upgrade your website. I would also recommend backing everything up before you attempt it. We normally will upgrade a site 5 or 6 times before we actually do it live. We document each step to ensure there are no hiccups when it really counts.

I think you are ok to 1.9 now. It includes a great responsive theme that you can use for your next redesign!

Comment: Yes, 1.9 is better, just want to make sure that new design and upgrade doesnt miss out old features and database...